# In list of elements, put numbered indexes in ids or use an index selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

When creating an ordered list of elements, I can think of three reasonable ways to access one by index:

Give it a unique id with a number at the end and use string manipulation:

```
<ol>
 <li id="item-0"></li>
 <li id="item-1"></li>
 <li id="item-2"></li>
</ol>

...

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   $('#item-' + i).doWhatever();
}
```

give them the same class and use the `eq` selector:

```
<ol>
 <li class="item"></li>
 <li class="item"></li>
 <li class="item"></li>
</ol>

...

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   $('.item').eq(i).doWhatever();
}
```

or give them the same class and use the `nth-child` selector:

```
<ol>
 <li class="item"></li>
 <li class="item"></li>
 <li class="item"></li>
</ol>

...

for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   $('.item:nth-child(' + i + ')').doWhatever();
}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each? Are there other, better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a fourth test case to your perf test: http://jsperf.com/item1-vs-item-eq-1/2

Considering your points in order:

- **Speed** It's easily the fastest method of those presented
- **String manipulation** None
- **Indexing** Starts from 0
- **Styling** You can style based on the parent, or you may choose to add additional class(es) to the list items themselves
- **Portability** That could just have easily been implemented with `getElementById` and `childNodes`

The main thing to consider, I think, is that all of your methods involve repeatedly querying the DOM as you're iterating through the list. If you're only ever accessing a single element, that's not a big deal, but if you're going to be working through the entire list, then only making a single query is going to make a big difference performance-wise.

**EDIT** Out of curiosity, I [updated my case again](http://jsperf.com/item1-vs-item-eq-1/4) not to use jQuery for locating the list at all, instead just using the barebones DOM API as I'd mentioned above.
Even with the changes Sandor made after pointing out my dumb mistake, there's a noticeable performance impact. With that in mind, I'd say it's mostly going to come down to your specific use case and how you weigh speed versus versatility in locating your list items.

Comment: I made some changes to your test case, because in your fourth you were performing a get operation with `text()` and in all other you were performing a set operation `text(i)`. the results are a little bit different http://jsperf.com/item1-vs-item-eq-1/3

Comment: I just noticed that; thanks for the update! I didn't read the tests closely enough :)

Answer (score 4):

A few differences come to mind:

- **Speed:** (at least on Chrome) the first is about twice as fast as the others, according to these test cases: http://jsperf.com/item1-vs-item-eq-1
- **String manipulation:** the second is the only one that doesn't require it
- **Indexing from 0 or 1:** the third is indexed from 1 rather than 0, which could cause problems depending on how you build/access the HTML
- **Styling:** if you want to style all of the elements similarly, the second and third don't require any additional classes
- **Portability:** if you have to change frameworks, the first and third may be more portable because they use standard CSS selectors

Comment: "the first is about twice as fast as the others" Naturally since you're selecting by id.

Comment: I had heard ids are faster, but I guess I didn't realize by how much.